# Datagridview foreach

Tags: c#, datagridview

I coded this for my code what im trying to do is for each of the accounts made in a database it adds it to the datagridviewi tried this code but all the comums are empty?

```
public DataTable GetResultsTable(string Username)
{
    using (SqlDatabaseClient client = SqlDatabaseManager.GetClient())
    {
        DataRow row = client.ExecuteQueryRow("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '" + Username + "'");
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        table.Columns.Add("Username".ToString());
        table.Columns.Add("Motto".ToString());
        table.Columns.Add("Email".ToString());
        table.Columns.Add("Homeroom".ToString());
        table.Columns.Add("Health".ToString());
        table.Columns.Add("Energy".ToString());
        table.Columns.Add("Age".ToString());
        DataRow dr = table.NewRow();
        dr["Username"] = "" + row["username"] + "";
        dr["Motto"] = "" + row["motto"] + "";
        dr["Email"] = "" + row["mail"] + "";
        dr["Homeroom"] = "" + row["home_room"] + "";
        dr["Health"] = "" + row["health"] + "";
        dr["Energy"] = "" + row["energy"] + "";
        dr["Age"] = "" + row["age"] + "";
        table.Rows.Add(dr);
        return table;
    }
}
public frmMain()
{
  this.InitializeComponent();
  this.SetupBackstageContent();
  ribbonControl1.SelectedRibbonTabItem = ribbonTabItem1;
  ribbonTabItem2.Text = "&USER CONTROL";
  ribbonTabItem4.Text = "&ADD ONS";

  SqlDatabaseManager.Initialize();
  using (SqlDatabaseClient client  = SqlDatabaseManager.GetClient())
  foreach (DataRow row2 in client.ExecuteQueryTable("SELECT * FROM users").Rows)
  {
      dataGridView1.DataSource = GetResultsTable((string)row2["username"]);
  }
}
```

Comment: A little confusing to see what you're trying to accomplish. Can you just loop through the datatable?

Answer (score 0):

Your way is wrong,if you want fill dataGrid with all user records just consider this code:

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("your connection string"))
        {
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM users", conn);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = ds;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Conn();
int i = 0;
cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from tbl_Emp", con);
da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
dt = new DataTable();
da.Fill(dt);
if (dt != null && dt.Rows.Count > 0)
{
if (Dgv_Emp.Rows.Count > 0)
{ Dgv_Emp.Rows.Clear(); }
Dgv_Emp.Rows.Add(dt.Rows.Count);
foreach (DataRow rw in dt.Rows)
{
Dgv_Emp.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value = rw["Emp_id"].ToString();
Dgv_Emp.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value = rw["Emp_name"].ToString();
Dgv_Emp.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value = rw["Emp_desg"].ToString();
Dgv_Emp.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value = rw["Emp_dept"].ToString();
Dgv_Emp.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value = rw["Emp_gender"].ToString();
Dgv_Emp.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value = rw["Emp_contact"].ToString();
i = i + 1;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use following code:

```
    public DataTable GetResultsTable()
    {
        using (SqlDatabaseClient client = SqlDatabaseManager.GetClient())
        {
            DataTable _userTable = client.ExecuteQueryTable("SELECT * FROM users");
            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            table.Columns.Add("Username".ToString());
            table.Columns.Add("Motto".ToString());
            table.Columns.Add("Email".ToString());
            table.Columns.Add("Homeroom".ToString());
            table.Columns.Add("Health".ToString());
            table.Columns.Add("Energy".ToString());
            table.Columns.Add("Age".ToString());
            foreach (DataRow _row in _userTable.Rows)
            {
                DataRow dr = table.NewRow();
                dr["Username"] = "" + _row["username"] + "";
                dr["Motto"] = "" + _row["motto"] + "";
                dr["Email"] = "" + _row["mail"] + "";
                dr["Homeroom"] = "" + _row["home_room"] + "";
                dr["Health"] = "" + _row["health"] + "";
                dr["Energy"] = "" + _row["energy"] + "";
                dr["Age"] = "" + _row["age"] + "";
                table.Rows.Add(dr);
            }

            return table;
        }
    }
    public frmMain()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.SetupBackstageContent();
        ribbonControl1.SelectedRibbonTabItem = ribbonTabItem1;
        ribbonTabItem2.Text = "&USER CONTROL";
        ribbonTabItem4.Text = "&ADD ONS";

        SqlDatabaseManager.Initialize();

        dataGridView1.DataSource = GetResultsTable();
    }
```

Since u r passing DataRow as DataSource for DataGridView view hence only last row would be in datagridview. Here I change ur code and bind DataTable rather than DataRow with DataSource of DataGridView.